# Cannot see the current html file

Tags: server, centos, cloudflare, litespeed

1. sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
2. Cloudflare cache
3. Digitalocean cdn cache
4. lscache folder inside remove

although I have done all of the operations I mentioned above, I cannot see the current html file.
I also deleted the history of my computer.

Comment: Server OS: CentOS 7

Comment: The system cache, or lscache may not relate to this issue. Do you have a browser cache? If you curl -I the html URL, what's the output?